# How to solve 'Cannot read property of undefined'

Tags: javascript, pagination, graphql, gatsby

I'm using a JS based static site generator, Gatsby, and I am trying to create a page for each category while paginating the same page. 
This is my code in gatsby-node.js, which is getting the error 'Cannot read property 'kebabCase' of undefined'.

```
        let categories = []
        _.each(result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges, edge => {
            if (_.get(edge, "node.frontmatter.categories")) {
                categories = categories.concat(edge.node.frontmatter.categories)
            }
        })

        const categoryarticles = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
        const categoryarticlesPerPage = 6
        const numPages = Math.ceil(categoryarticles.length / categoryarticlesPerPage)

        Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
            categories.forEach(category => {
                createPage({
                    path: i === 0 ? `/${_.kebabCase(category)}` : `/${_.kebabCase(category)}/${i + 1}`,
                    component: managementTemplate,
                    context: {
                        category,
                        limit: categoryarticlesPerPage,
                        skip: i * categoryarticlesPerPage,
                    },
                })
            })
        })
```

category is actually defined and in fact when I create the category page without trying to paginate, the code categories.forEach(category ... ect works fine. 
What am I missing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That error doesn't say `category` is undefined. It says `_` is undefined.

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing it out. At the top of the file I am defining const _ = require("lodash") though, so shouldn't it be defined as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Array#foreach loop is shadowing `_`, so that it no longer refers to lodash. It refers to the current array value, which is `undefined`.

Change `.forEach((_, i)` and use a different variable name so that you don't shadow `_`. Eg. `.forEach((el, i)`.